# Are there grants that sponsor transition into faculty positions (K99, etc) in not biology-adjacent fields?

Tags: career-path, funding, faculty-application

In my field (biophysics), I know of a few grants that can be received as a postdoc, which provide funding both as a postdoc and as a new faculty member.  One example is the NIH K99 "Pathway to Independence" award; another is the Burroughs Wellcome Career Award.  These can act as hiring incentives, and in some biology fields, the K99 is seen as a near-guarantee of finding a faculty position.

Are there similar grants for other fields, or is this a quirk of the bio-adjacent world?  How are these sorts of grants viewed in other fields?

EDITED TO ADD: To my knowledge, there is no such grant for the NSF (the most obvious source).  A few ones I hadn't mentioned are listed here, but they are all biomedical: [Ohio State](http://medicine.osu.edu/research_ed/postdoc/current_postdocs/funding/career_grants/pages/index.aspx) .

Comment: One small suggested improvement on your question: Most of these kinds of public grants are available through myriad resources.  For instance, the NIH lists all available grants on their Web site.  So maybe if you provide a list of sources you've tried to check?  Just so no one repeats your efforts.  Or maybe you aren't aware of these sources which refocuses your question...

Comment: Dave - I'm asking about fields where I don't know the most common sources of funding, so the starting point isn't that obvious.  I'm also curious about how people view the grants, which is something only available directly from people.

Comment: I removed the part of the question that polls for people's opinions. See the [help/dont-ask] for more details.